# Disabling a Jbutton in java when another Jbutton is pressed

Tags: java, jframe

My code is:

```
public FactoryWindow()
{
    getPreferredSize();
    setTitle("Bounce");
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    add(comp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    addButton(buttonPanel, "Circle", new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                comp.addShape();
            }
        });
    addButton(buttonPanel, "Machine", new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                comp.addMachine();

            }
        });
    addButton(buttonPanel, "Close", new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    pack();
}
```

This is a constructor. the class extends JFrame

```
public void addButton(Container c, String title, ActionListener listener)
{
   JButton button = new JButton(title);
   c.add(button);
   button.addActionListener(listener);
}
```

I want to be able to disable the Shape button when I press the machine button

How would I go about doing that?

I know there is Something like `buttonName.setEnabled(false);` but I cannot figure out how to use it in this context.

Comment: You will need a reference to the button you are trying to disable

Comment: Sorry the button I am trying to disable is the "Circle" button, when the "Machine" button is pressed

Answer (score 1):

You will need a reference to the button you are trying to disable, this will require you to change your code slightly...

First, you need your `addButton` method to return the button it created...

```
public JButton addButton(Container c, String title, ActionListener listener) {
    JButton button = new JButton(title);
    c.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(listener);
    return button;
}
```

Then you need to assign the result to a variable...

```
JButton cirlce = null;
JButton machine = null;

cirlce = addButton(buttonPanel, "Circle", new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        comp.addShape();
    }
});
```

Then you can access it from your `ActionListener`...

```
machine = addButton(buttonPanel, "Machine", new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        comp.addMachine();
        circle.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Now, if you're using Java 6 (and I think Java 7), it will complain that the button should be `final`, but this won't work based on the way you have your code set up.  Instead, you will need to make `circle` and `machine` instance fields in order to be able to access them from within the `ActionListener` context